# Checking intersection between polygon and geometry in GeoJSON

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, intersect

I have a GeoJSON file with different geometries(polygons). I'd like to find if my polygon intersects with any of the file's geometry.
I am not going to paste the file here as it is a long one, but can be found here:  https://flightplan.romatsa.ro/init/static/zone_restrictionate_uav.json

Here is what I have done, but it returns false when it should return true:

```
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

df = geopandas.read_file("geometries.json") 
lat_point_list = [46.384215727080694, 46.42583525049556, 46.40743997749065]
lon_point_list = [24.66499565544466, 24.699163210220682, 24.706980760567422]

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lat_point_list, lon_point_list))
df1 = geopandas.GeoSeries({'geometry': polygon_geom}).set_crs(4326)

for geo in df["geometry"]:
    ctr = geopandas.GeoSeries({'geometry': geo}).set_crs(4326)
    if ctr.intersects(df1)[0]:
        print(ctr)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Heyo Alin. Good question. It's easier for people to answer if you have a code example without a file that needs to be read since people don't have your file.

Comment: Thank you Davma for pointing out, I attached a link to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shapely use (x,y) in the geometries and not (y,x), therefore:

```
polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list,lat_point_list))
df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':[polygon_geom]})
for geo in df["geometry"]:
    if geo.intersects(df1.geometry[0]):
        print(geo)
POLYGON ((24.14861107 46.46777725, 24.63750076 46.5633316, 24.69666672 46.41916656, 24.20750046 46.32361221, 24.14861107 46.46777725))
```